# How to run script on remote pc

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run a powershell script on remote pc . if i put the path in variable it does not run, but if i put the path as string it works. Not sure why.

This works

```
Invoke-Command -computername $serverName -scriptblock {& ("C:\_Project\test.ps1") }
```

This does not work

```
$server = "test"

$script = "C:\_Project\test.ps1"

Invoke-Command -computername $server -scriptblock {& ( $script) }
```

I would like to get the 2nd one working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables need to be passed to script blocks as arugments or they won't be available in the scriptblock. Here is how to do it.

```
$server = "test"
$script = "C:\_Project\test.ps1"
Invoke-Command -computername $server -ArugmentList $Script -scriptblock {
Param ($Script)
& ( $script)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```powershell
$server = "test"
$script = [ScriptBlock]::Create("& C:\_Project\test.ps1")
Invoke-Command -computername $server -scriptblock $script
```